# How to get the Desktop path in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a cross platform way to get the Dekstop path in Ruby ?

Answer (score 4):

`ENV['HOME'] + '/Desktop'` should work on all windows.
I'm not sure about osx, and linux often doesn't have a desktop

Comment: In older versions (e.g. XP) of non-English Windows the Desktop folder is not necessarily called "Desktop". For example it could be named `桌面` in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Dir.pwd to get current path.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#M002316

Answer (score 0):

ENV['HOME']+'/Desktop' should work on all windows and OSX